# Changing disk space allocation

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

I have disk space allocated as per below.

```
Model: INTEL RS2BL040 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1998GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
```

```
Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  512MB   511MB   primary  ext3            boot
 2      512MB   922GB   922GB   primary  ext4
 3      922GB   1998GB  1076GB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
```

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   1,8T  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   487M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0 858,3G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0  1002G  0 part [SWAP]
```

I would like to change my swap partition to 32GB and add that left over space to the sda2 drive how can I do this from a command line.

Thanks

Comment: woow 1TB for swap

Answer (score -1):

You can't resize while Ubuntu is running.
Here is the easiest solution:

1. Download [GParted](http://gparted.org/liveusb.php).
2. Make a boot to CD or USB then boot it.
3. Resize the 1TB swap partition.

**Note**: swap = RAM + 2.

Comment: Yeah I know 1tb is insane. I have installed gparted with apt-get the problem is this site is sitting in a data centre and its a mission to take a cd or usb there. Thats why I was wondering if it could be done through command line.

Comment: If this is the solution you are looking for, please mark it done

Comment: Actually, it *is* possible -- or at least, it *may be* possible, depending on what filesystem was used, and it should be fine with ext4fs. This is a duplicate question, though. In this case, I'd disable swap space, delete the swap partition, resize the filesystem partition, and then create a new swap partition.